# Deploy option missing from Project menu for Azure Resource Group

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-resource-group, azure-sdk

I have created an Azure Resource Group project in Visual Studio 2015 and I am unable to see a "Deploy" option. It was there last week, but now it is missing.

It doesn't show up for neither new projects nor existing projects. I've tried to uninstall/reinstall the Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2015 and restarting my machine; neither had an affect.

Any help would be appreciated.